# Extending a collection of objects by the repeated application of a collection of functions

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, terminology

I am trying to find the correct terminology for a process. The following description is handwavy but the goal is to give the idea of the process I am trying to describe mathematically.

We start with a collection (/set/category/...?) $\mathcal{C_{0}}$ of objects $c_{i}$ and a collection $\mathcal{F}$ of functions $f_{i}$ (/maps/morphisms/...?) that can be applied to every object $c_{i}$ in $\mathcal{C}$. The arity of the functions can be anything (some can take one argument, some others two, some others three, etc...). Now we apply the following process: at each step $n$, all the functions $f_{i}$ are applied to all the objects in $\mathcal{C_{n}}$ and all the combinations of objects (for the functions that takes more than one argument) to produce $\mathcal{C_{n+1}}$ as the union of $\mathcal{C_{n}}$ and the results of the application of the functions. We call $\mathcal{C}$ the collection of objects obtained at infinity.

Is there anything in set theory or category theory (or other domains of maths) that would resemble something along these lines and where (ideally) $\mathcal{C_{0}}$, $\mathcal{F}$, and $\mathcal{C}$ would have an associated terminology. I am not necessarily looking for an exact correspondence with what I described (which is very handwavy anyway), but I am looking for mathematical notions/entry points to investigate around the idea.

Illustration: if $\mathcal{C}_{0} = \{2\}$ and $\mathcal{F} = \{f, g\}$ where $f$ is the function that gives the next prime number if given a prime number, and $0$ otherwise and where $g$ is the product of two numbers, ultimately $\mathcal{C} = \mathbb{N} \setminus \{1\}$ (if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, given a set of operators $\mathcal F$ on a set $X$, and given a subset $Y\subseteq X$, it would seem natural to say something like "the $\mathcal F$-closure of $X$" to denote the new subset of $X$ obtained by applying things in $\mathcal F$ until nothing new is obtained.

I'm not sure if there is an impediment to relaxing this to include operators on a proper class rather than a set, but perhaps there is, depending on what the operators do.

As a special case, if you are viewing a group $G$ acting on a set $X$, the $G$-closure of a single element is called an *orbit*.